# How can I use the fields in the class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

```
class TPCANTimestamp (Structure):
    """
    Represents a timestamp of a received PCAN message
    Total Microseconds = micros + 1000 * millis + 0x100000000 * 1000 * millis_overflow
    """
    _fields_ = [ ("millis", c_uint),           # Base-value: milliseconds: 0.. 2^32-1
                 ("millis_overflow", c_ushort), # Roll-arounds of millis
                 ("micros", c_ushort) ]
```

How can I use the fields in the `TPCANTimestamp`  class?

Comment: if you do `dir(TPCANTimestamp)`, you will get a list of methods and attributes that you can call on your objects.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I **use** the fields in the TPCANTimestamp class?

Use them as `Structure`'s attributes:

```
from ctypes import *


class TPCANTimestamp(Structure):
    """
    Represents a timestamp of a received PCAN message
    Total Microseconds = micros + 1000 * millis + 0x100000000 * 1000 * millis_overflow
    """
    _fields_ = [ ("millis", c_uint),           # Base-value: milliseconds: 0.. 2^32-1
                 ("millis_overflow", c_ushort), # Roll-arounds of millis
                 ("micros", c_ushort)]

t = TPCANTimestamp(100, 20, 30)
print(t.millis, t.micros)
```

The output:

```
100 30
```